# What is the type of `main0` function?

Tags: ats

What is the type of `main0` function?

I'm writing gtk3 library. However the `g_application_run()` function needs `argv`.
Of course, ATS language can use `argv` on `main0` function. But what is the type?

Answer (score 1):

The following code is declared in prelude/basics_dyn.dats:

```
//
symintr main0
//
fun
main_void_0
  ((*void*)): void = "ext#mainats_void_0"
fun
main_argc_argv_0
  {n:int | n >= 1}
  (argc: int n, argv: !argv(n)): void = "ext#mainats_argc_argv_0"
//
overload main0 with main_void_0
overload main0 with main_argc_argv_0
//
```

As you can see, `main0` is overloaded with `main_void_0` and `main_argc_argv_0`. The type `argv(n)` is essentially for a linear string array of size `n` that ends with the null value. Note that the null value is not counted as part of the size.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My issue is fixed:

Comment: https://github.com/metasepi/c2ats/commit/bbe91528f3d0a9a860c2460b4f5419f049ed9e91